# State Variable is Not Updated in React Const Function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, zustand

I have an app where I am trying to make a network request upon component load to set a projectId using an API call and set the state via zustand. In addition, there are calls to listen to a web socket upgrade to update something on the frontend using the results.

For example,

```
const Component = () => {
  const { setProjectIdStorage } = useProjectStore();

  const projectIdStorage = useProjectStore((state) => state.projectIdStorage);

  useEffect(() => {
    createProject();
  }, []);

 function createProject() {
    BackendClient.post(
      `projects`,
      { project_id: projectIdStorage },
      { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } },
    )
      .then((response) => {
        setProjectIdStorage(response.data.project.id);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Failed to create project");
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("server_recommendation", onServerRecommendation);
    socket.on("server_code", onServerCode);
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

const refreshProjectStates = (projectId: string | null) => {
    BackendClient.post(
      `projects/project_state`,
      { project_id: projectId },
      { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } },
    ).then(async (response: any) => {
      const projectStates = response.data.project_states;
      setProjectStates(projectStates);
      if (projectStates.length > 0) {
        setActiveProjectState(projectStates[projectStates.length - 1]);
      }
    });
  };

const refreshRecommendations = (projectId: string | null) => {
    BackendClient.get(
      `recommendations?project_id=${projectId}`
    ).then((response) => {
      setRecommendations(response.data.recommendations);
    })    
  }

const onServerCode = () => {
    setLoading(false);
    refreshProjectStates(projectIdStorage);
    setPrompt("");
  };

  const onServerRecommendation = () => {
    refreshRecommendations(projectIdStorage);
  };
}
```

The problem I am having is that after the first network request of CreateProject() AND the projectID is set - the projectId when accessed further down in the refreshProjectState/refreshRecommendations are always NULL. However, it seems to work only after the page is refreshed.

I am using Zustand in this example but it seems to fail with regular react useState() as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `onServerCode` and `onServerRecommendation` have a stale closure over the initial `projectIdStorage` state that is selected.

Update the `useEffect` hook to use a dependency on the `projectIdStorage` value so that the server event handlers have the current project id value.

Example:

```js
const projectIdStorage = useProjectStore((state) => state.projectIdStorage);

useEffect(() => {
  // Disconnect/close socket on component unmount
  return () => {
    socket.disconnect();
  };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  const refreshProjectStates = (projectId: string | null) => {
    BackendClient.post(
      `projects/project_state`,
      { project_id: projectId },
      { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } },
    )
      .then(async (response: any) => {
        const projectStates = response.data.project_states;
        setProjectStates(projectStates);
        if (projectStates.length > 0) {
          setActiveProjectState(projectStates[projectStates.length - 1]);
        }
      });
  };

  const refreshRecommendations = (projectId: string | null) => {
    BackendClient.get(`recommendations?project_id=${projectId}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setRecommendations(response.data.recommendations);
      });    
  };

  const onServerCode = () => {
    setLoading(false);
    refreshProjectStates(projectIdStorage);
    setPrompt("");
  };

  const onServerRecommendation = () => {
    refreshRecommendations(projectIdStorage);
  };

  socket.on("server_recommendation", onServerRecommendation);
  socket.on("server_code", onServerCode);

  return () => {
    socket.off("server_recommendation", onServerRecommendation);
    socket.off("server_code", onServerCode);
  };
}, [projectIdStorage]);
```

Comment: Could you help me understand the concept of this "stale closure"? I am trying to read more about it but cannot.

Comment: In addition - is there a better way to write the code so that not all of the functions need to be in that useEffect clause?

Comment: @KaiMou (1) Ah, sorry, the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) is basically that `socket.on` is passed a copy, i.e. an "instance", of a callback function, which includes a copy of any variables it references, within its closure. Those values will forever be those values for the life of the function, thus the "staleness". The solution above effectively attaches a *new* copy with updated values closed over in the function scope.

Comment: @KaiMou (2) Better, that is subjective, but you could move them out of the effect callback if you wanted. You could declare these functions external to the `useEffect`, but since they are external they then become dependencies. Since the functions would be declared each render cycle you wouldn't them, as *new* references, triggering the `useEffect` hook to run more often than you want it to. To fix this you can memoize the function reference with the `useCallback` hook with a dependency array for any of *its* dependencies. Does this help your understanding?